# Java - Compare 2 HTML strings and return the mismatched objects

Tags: java, selenium, compare

I have two 1 line innerHTML strings (fairly large) and I need to compare them and if they don't match, I need to know which objects are different. Example:

HTML 1:

```
<div><p><span class="text">MyText</span></p></div>
```

HTML 2:

```
<div><p><span class="text">NotMyText</span></p></div>
```

Should give the list of objects back, only 1 item in this case:

```
<span class="text">NotMyText</span>
```

I'm running the script on thousands of links/pages, so the speed is very important. I tried Google Diff, which only returns the parts that do not match. It would say that MyText has been removed and NotMyText has been added or something similar, but that is not what I need.

Any idea on this?

Comment: Can you clarify more the criteria for why they are different? e.g.
1. Is it only tags with changed content, or
2. It needs to give xml output
3. Only the last object?

Comment: Maybe an xpath or xslt library might help

Comment: Also see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/371034, just noticed that you were using selenium which I've no experience with, sorry

Comment: Thanks for your answers. The data which renders the HTML is compressed on one page (spaces, line breaks removed) and not compressed on the other, which might cause the HTML to render differently. I'm not using Selenium to tell the difference, it is just the tool that runs the browsers and gets me the innerHTML strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should not do the comparison on String Level, because from the String diff it's not easy to find out where you are, what's the enclosing element. If you work on a DOM tree representation, it should be much easier to do.

If I were you I would write a recursive DOM comparison method and do a kind of depth-first search on the complete tree like this (just pseudocode):

```
DomDifference compare(DOMElement a, DOMElement b) {
   if(a.isLeaf()) {
     return DomDiff(a, b)
   }
   foreach(child: a.children()) {
     otherChild = b.nextChild()
     result = compare(child, otherChild);
     if(!result.isEqual()) {
       return result;
     }
   }
   return DomDifference.nodesAreEqual;
}
```

Comment: This was my first idea, which I tried to avoid since breaking down the html and looping through the objects to find the difference is a bit heavy, especially when running on thousands of pages. Maybe using your idea along with Google Diff might be the solution, maybe if I only break down the HTML when Google Diff found a mismatch wouldn't slow down the execution that much.. Thanks for your answer.